# How to implement permanent login with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-authorization

I am implementing devise user authentication on a Rails 4 App and was wondering how do I stop the App from logging the User out after a certain amount of time. I want a user not to be signed out unless they click the sign out button, I believe this is called permanent login.

Comment: Are you asking about a remember me type login?

Comment: Yea, I don't want users to have to click remember me though, I want the app to remember them automagically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look inside `config/initializers/devise.rb` you will find configuration settings that include `config.timeout_in`.

It is also possible to set it within the model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :timeoutable, timeout_in: 15.minutes
end
```

Check [this link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-timeout_in-value-dynamically) for more information.